# Extract specific text from a document using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file that I need to extract specific data elements from.

Example text:

```
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/example0.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-01-22</lastmod>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/example1.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-01-21</lastmod>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/example2.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-01-21</lastmod>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/example3.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-01-20</lastmod>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/example4.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-01-20</lastmod>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
```

I want to extract:

```
https://example.com/example0.html
https://example.com/example1.html
https://example.com/example2.html
https://example.com/example3.html
https://example.com/example4.html
```

**Please keep in mind that the date is not static**

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? Do you want to remove everything but URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<url>\s+<loc>(\S+?)</loc>.+?</url>`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<url>       # literally
  \s+       # 1 or more any spaces, including linebreak
  <loc>     # literally
  (\S+?)    # group 1, 1 or more non spaces, not greedy
  </loc>    # literally
  .+?       # 1 or more any characters, not greedy
</url>      # literally
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, the URL
```

**Result for given example:**

```
https://example.com/example0.html
https://example.com/example1.html
https://example.com/example2.html
https://example.com/example3.html
https://example.com/example4.html
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a simpler way, and I don't have access to Notepad++ right now but you can try the following

Search: `<url>\n\s+<loc>(.*)<\/loc>\n\s.*\n\s.*\n<\/url>`

Replace: `\1`

> Source [regexr.com/46rin](http://regexr.com/46rin)

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work Error message : no occurrence was found